# Check if "Save" button is clicked from Service Cloud Console or Standard layout

Tags: apex, custom-button, service-cloud-console

I have page reference method written on click of "Save" button. I need to refresh one page after click of Save button when in console and not when in standard Salesforce.

```
 PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VisualforcepageName?Id='+idAccount+'&isdtp=vw');
    return pr;
```

How can we check in Apex whether button was clicked when in Console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the save method on the source page to an onclick event instead of an action.  Then use a JavaScript method to check inconsole and depending on result pass different or additional parameter to the controller to evaluate on your actual save method execution.