# closeTab on Save in Console; redirect not in console

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, commandbutton, salesforce-classic

How do I close a tab on Save in the Service console, but redirect the user when in Sales Cloud?

Specifically, when a user clicks a button from a related list in the Case page, I walk them through a wizard.  When that wizard is done, I want the user's experience to be "finished", whatever that means.  "Finished" in Sales Cloud means that they are back at the Case page.  "Finished" in Service Console means that the subtab is closed, and they are looking at the Details subtab.

I have tried `onclick`, but that happens too soon.  I have tried `oncomplete`, but that only happens on AJAX calls.  This code is quite fragile and now is not the time for a refactor.  I would love an Apex or VF method that mirrors `sforce.console.isInConsole()`, but I cannot find that.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Pretty similar: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29175/check-if-save-button-is-clicked-from-service-cloud-console-or-standard-layout Though it doesn't seem like Jim's solution is working for you.

Comment: Well, I didn't try using `actionFunction`, believe it or not, but I'm looking to _close_ the tab, not send the user elsewhere.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah - just tried that path.  The code that I'm working around is pretty fragile and I don't want to update it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a `Boolean` property to tell you if you are in the console, consider using an `actionFunction` or some similar mechanism to propagate that data from the client.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!flagConsole}" name="setConsole" rerender="none" />
    </apex:form>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            if (typeof(srcUp) == 'function') { setConsole(); }
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public Boolean isInConsole { get; private set; }
    public Throwaway()
    {
        isInConsole = false;
    }
    public void flagConsole() { isInConsole = true; }
}
```

Comment: This is actually terrific for other cases.  +1! (yes, 1 factorial)  But... Apex can't close a tab, so... how does this help?  I guess the `actionFunction` can rerender an `actionRegion` which declares a javascript function in it?  Or perhaps the `commandButton` can be rerendered?

Comment: Oh you just said in your OP *I would love an Apex or VF method that mirrors sforce.console.isInConsole(), but I cannot find that.* Let's see now...

Comment: Ah.  The goal of that was to use a `rendered` attr on the `commandButton`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar conundrum now and perhaps a decent solution would be redirecting to a dummy Visualforce page that closes itself.

This way it works for both, save and cancel buttons. You still need to intelligently route to either VF page when in console and to parent record id when in classic (using Adrian's suggestion).